# PostgreSQL TIMESTAMPTZ is not working with SpringBoot Java Query

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

The SpringBoot Query returns null while using TIMESTAMPTZ as the Datatype, but the Query works for other Datatypes like TIMESTAMP etc. My Date formats are like, "2022-07-24 10:11:29.452+00".

The DB screenshot is added below.

[image]

Also the date type is defined as follows

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "datem")
private Date datem;
```

The API calls the below code

```
Date start = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").parse("2022-07-24 10:11:29.452+00");
Date end = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").parse("2022-07-24 10:11:49.452+00");

List<MqttMessageParsed> sensor_data = messageParsedRepository.findByCreatedAtBetween(start, end);
```

The Query function is as follows

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM MqttMessageParsed t WHERE t.datem BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate") List<MqttMessageParsed> findByCreatedAtBetween(@Param("startDate")Date start, @Param("endDate")Date end);
```

The API shoud return the data between the above start and end dates, but it is returning null now. Am i missing something?

Thanks

Comment: You should use instances of `ZonedDateTime` as the parameter value, not `java.util.Date` (or `java.sql.Date`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Did you mean to say `OffsetDateTime`?

Comment: In any case I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Do use `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) as Basil Bourque says in his answer.

Comment: You are not parsing the offset, `+00`, from your strings. `SimpleDateFormat` is probably assuming some other time zone, giving you results that are hours off, potentially up to 14 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Avoid legacy classes

You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes. Avoid `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat`, and `Timestamp`.

## *java.time*

For a column of a type akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, use the class `OffsetDateTime` in JDBC 4.2 and later.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

Writing:

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt);
```

Hibernate was years ago updated to support *java.time*. Ditto for *Jakarta Persistence*, formerly *Java Persistence API (JPA)*.

## ISO 8601

I suggest you educate the publisher of your inputs about the value of strict compliance with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard for date-time formats.

- Replace SPACE in the middle with a `T`.
- Use full offset with both hours and minutes, separated by a COLON character.

So this:

> "2022-07-24 10:11:29.452+00"

… should be:

> "2022-07-24T10:11:29.452+00:00"

… or alternatively use a `Z` as the suffix to indicate an offset of zero:

> "2022-07-24T10:11:29.452Z"

If you cannot effect that change, then define a custom formatting pattern to parse that non-standard format. Use `DateTimeFormatter` class, as has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow.

---

By the way, know that the other data type, `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` *cannot* be used to record a moment, a specific point on the timeline. This type stores only a date and a time-of-day without the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. So, for example, given the date of last January 23rd at 12:00, we cannot know if that meant noon in Tokyo Japan, noon in Toulouse France, or noon in Toledo Ohio US — three different moments several hours apart.

If you need to track when something happened, always use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. In the case of [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html), any time zone or offset info supplied with an input is used to adjust to UTC (an offset of zero) and then discarded. The moment is **always stored in UTC**, in Postgres for this type. If you care about the original time zone, store that in a second column.

Comment: Hmm i have also tried the OffsetDateTime, but it didnt worked for me. Can you add some more code details in your answer. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Ansif I do not use Spring, so that’s as far as I can help you. I’ll bet you can find code examples on existing Answers to other Questions.

Comment: Ok i did a partial fix to the above problem. I have changed the Datatype from TIMESTAMPTZ to TIMESTAMP in my Database and the query is working now.  Anyway the real is fix is based on your solution. I will mark this as the correct answer. Thanks Basil Bourque

Comment: It certainly is. A `timestamp` without time zone cannot define a point in time so despite the name is unsuited for a timestamp.